# Connection String to Connect to .MDF

Tags: connection-string, sql-server-express, mdf, datadirectory

I've created a new project in VS2008, and added a .MDF file to the project.  This is the first time I've tried to use the MDF files and .SQLEXPRESS databases (I've always used extenal Oracle servers in the past).

I'm trying to document everything as I go, but I can't figure out what credentials are being used to connect to the .MDF file.  Is there an easy way to find out?

Comment: [http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you're using the *.mdf file in the App_Data folder of an ASP.NET app you can use this.

> Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;

If it's not an ASP.NET application don't use the DataDirectory syntax and just use the full c:\... path.

Answer (score 0):

from where this name mydbfile ?

If you're using the *.mdf file in the App_Data folder of an ASP.NET app you can use this.

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|**mydbfile**.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

If it's not an ASP.NET application don't use the DataDirectory syntax and just use the full c:... path.

Answer (score 0):

For a local DB and no SQLEXPRESS server:

```
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=""|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdf"";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
```