# how to manage connection to aspnetdb in web config?

Tags: asp.net, aspnetdb

I use login control in asp.net. this control creating a aspnetdb.mdf file in app_data folder and there is not any code in web config for connection to this db. in local web is working as correct but when web on IIs can not to conection to the aspnetdb. how to manage connection to aspnetdb by web config? 
I use follow cod in my web.config but when aspnetdb attach to sqlserver the web not working :

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLMIRZA;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|ASPNETDB.MDF;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: if your webserver has sqlserver on it you could attach the mdf file to the sqlserver and then use it.

Comment: There is a default `connectionstring` in the web.config file. It might be using that.

Comment: check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928813/connection-string-to-connect-to-mdf

Comment: when I attach the aspnetdb.mdf not work at local hast, altough I add connection string for aspnetdb on sql server in web.config

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

One observation is that you are giving the full path of the `mdf` file in the connection string. `|DataDirectory|` directory automatically points to the `App_Date` folder. so no need to give the full physical path of the `mdf` file. this should also work -

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLMIRZA;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

to connect to `mdf` file directly you need `SQLEXPRESS` installed on your machine. check if your web server has `SQLEXPRESS` instance installed.

if you instead attach the file to `MSSQLSERVER` instance. then your connection string should be changed to something like this -

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=(local);Initial Catalog=ASPNETDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

if this connection string doesn't work on your local machine then you can keep both in your `web.config` and comment out one. something like this -

```
<!-- LOCAL -->
<add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLMIRZA;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<!--REAL-->
<!--<add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLMIRZA;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
```

here I have commented out the real/web connection string, so it will work on local machine.
before deploying just just reverse the comments and it will work on web.