# datacontext create connnectionstring

Tags: c#, windows, forms, datacontext

I'm trying to write a Windows Form app. I need to use a database and since I know how to create a db in WP8 (using Datacontext) I tried to use the same class with this form project.
I have a problem: how can I define the connectionstring in the StudentDatacontext class in order to create a local database in the folder of my application?

(I aleready tried using

```
public static string ConnectionString = @"c:\students.mdf";
```

but my application explodes on db.CreateDatabase();

```
    using (StudenteDataContext db = new StudenteDataContext(StudenteDataContext.ConnectionString))
            {
                if (!db.DatabaseExists())
                {
                    db.CreateDatabase();
                }

)
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: yeah.  we need to see the exact error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connection String to Connect to .MDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928813/connection-string-to-connect-to-mdf)

Comment: @eisenhom can you please tell me if the syntax of the connectionstring is correct?

Comment: You can check that out yourself at connectionstrings.com Also this might be a relevant read for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173209/how-do-i-connect-to-an-mdf-microsoft-sql-server-database-file-in-a-simple-web

Comment: Ok, I may have undeerstood my mistake and I need someone to please explain me if I'm right: on WP8 I used to create a local database, a file, in the internal memory, and datacontext used to do the remaining work. Now on Windows form application do I have to connect to a sql server (or something like that) in order to use a database (a local database, stored in myprojec folder) ? Or I can behave like Iused in WP8 ?